# Can I deduce the previous row from a DGV's DefaultValuesNeeded event?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to be able to copy the values from the previous row to the new row as a user enters it by doing something like this in my DGV's DefaultValuesNeeded() event:

```
private void dataGridViewPlatypi_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs args)
{
    dataGridViewRow dgvr = args.PreviousRow;
    args.Row.Cells[1].Value = dgvr.Cells[1].Value;
    args.Row.Cells[2].Value = dgvr.Cells[2].Value;
    args.Row.Cells[3].Value = dgvr.Cells[3].Value;
    args.Row.Cells[4].Value = dgvr.Cells[4].Value;;
    args.Row.Cells[5].Value = dgvr.Cells[5].Value;
}
```

...however, I don't know if it's possible to programmatically deduce the previous row (there is no "PreviousRow" property of args as I wishfully thinking show above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer my question as posed, because it only copies one cell at a time, rather than the entire row, but it really suits my purposes (copy from the cell to the left in the first row, and from the cell above thereafter):

This works:

```
private void dataGridViewPlatypi_CellEnter(object sender,   DataGridViewCellEventArgs args)
{
    string prevVal = string.Empty;
    if (args.RowIndex > 0)
    {
        prevVal = dataGridViewPlatypi.Rows[args.RowIndex - 1].Cells[args.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
    } else if (args.ColumnIndex > 1)
    {
        prevVal = dataGridViewPlatypi.Rows[args.RowIndex].Cells[args.ColumnIndex-1].Value.ToString();
    }
    dataGridViewPlatypi.Rows[args.RowIndex].Cells[args.ColumnIndex].Value = prevVal;
}
```